# How to hide all body elements before preloader finishes loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a full screen Preloader counter. And I need all my body elements to be hidden while the Preloader loads, and when it finishes, the other body elements such as *navbar* and *sections*, can be appeared on screen.

Here is my `html` code:

```
<body>
    <section class="preloader">
        <div class="loader"></div>
        <div class="count"></div>
    </section>
    <header>
    ...
    </header>
    <div id="fullpage">
    ...
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is the `CSS` of preloader:

```
.loader{
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.preloader{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    animation:fadeout 0.5s linear forwards;
    animation-delay:8.5s;
}
@keyframes fadeout
{
    0%
    {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100%
    {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
.count{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-size:18vw;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: 800;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    text-align:right;
}
```

And this also the `jQuery` part of Preloader:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    count = 0;
    counter = setInterval(function(){
        if(count < 101){
            $('.count').text(count + '%');
            $('.loader').css('width', count + '%');
            count++
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(counter)
        }
    }, 80)
});
```

So how can I hide *all* body elements until the Preloader finishes its progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give the preloader enough `z-index` to be on top of any other element on your screen.

```
.loader{
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.preloader{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with z-index in the preloader or hide the navbar and sidebar until the preloader ends.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    count = 0;
    counter = setInterval(function(){
        if(count < 101){
            $('.count').text(count + '%');
            $('.loader').css('width', count + '%');
            count++
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(counter)
            $(".sidebar").show();
            $(".navbar").show();
        }
    }, 80)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with Jquery. I don't have your HTML so I use a random one.

Note that I used `$('body').children().not('script').show();`, that's because here in StackOverflow, `show()` function shows script content.

```js
$('body').children().hide();
$('.preloader').show();
$(document).ready(function(){
    count = 0;
    counter = setInterval(function(){
        if(count < 101){
            $('.count').text(count + '%');
            $('.loader').css('width', count + '%');
            count++
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(counter)
            $('body').children().not('script').show();
            $('.preloader').hide();
        }
    }, 80)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <section class="preloader">
        <div class="loader"></div>
        <div class="count"></div>
    </section>
    <header>
      Hello
    </header>
    <div id="fullpage">
      World!
    </div>
</body>
```